# Do unitary matrices commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices

Physically, unitary matrices of the same dimension describes a rigid motion, so it feels like the order of the rigid motion doesn't really matter? So do unitary matrices commute?

Comment: Rotations don't commute.

Comment: Actually, they do. John would be correct if he added "with reflections" to his sentence: Rotations don't commute with reflections.

Comment: @CarlHeckman If you rotate $90$ degrees counter-clockwise around the $x$ axis followed by $90$ degrees counter-clockwise around the $z$ axis, does that commute? That would take $\hat i$ to $\hat j$. If I went the other way, $z$ axis first, that would take $\hat i$ to $\hat k$.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking in 2 dimensions. (My example works even in 2 dimensions, though.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rotations in $\mathbb R^3$ do not commute. Consider $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

and $$B=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -1 & 0 \\
        1 &  0 & 0 \\
        0 &  0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

$A$ is a rotation about the $x$ axis and $B$ is a rotation about the $z$ axis. I will leave it to you to verify that each has determinant $1$ and $AB\ne BA$.

Comment: Because they don't share the same eigenvectors? So two matrices commute if they share the same set of eigenvectors, is that generally true?

Comment: If $v$ is a common eigenvector of $A$ and $B$ it is true that $ABv=BAv$ but I would recommend looking at this example from a more intuitive point of view. Rotations don't commute.

Answer (score 0):

The unitary group $U(n)$ is not abelian for $n\gt1$.   The center $Z(U(n))$ is the set of all scalar matrices $\lambda I$, with $\lambda \in U(1)$, by Schur's lemma.